# Actions like CCMoveTo, CCRotateTo,CCBlink etc not working

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have created a loading scene separate class derived from CCScene which I can reuse in other projects. I have added a label called "Loading.." inside it.

```
@interface LoadingScene : CCScene
{
TargetScenes targetScene_;
}
```

I want to give effects to label while other scene is loading but I am not able to do so..

In .m file here goes the code for adding labels:

```
-(id) initWithTargetScene:(TargetScenes)targetScene
{
if ((self = [super init]))
{
targetScene_ = targetScene;

CCLabelTTF* label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Loading ..." fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:64];
label.color = ccWHITE;
CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
label.position = CGPointMake(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);
CCBlink *blink = [CCBlink actionWithDuration:2 blinks:10];
[label runAction:blink];
[self addChild:label];

}

return self;
}
```

The blink is not work.. None of the actions are working and giving me big headache...

Please can someone let me know the reason behind it? Also, How to overcome it?

Comment: Have you overridden onEnter in your class? Did you remember to call `[super onEnter]`

Comment: Works perfectly... This is awesome!! Thanks for the help.. But, what's the need to over-ride it?

Comment: Had you already overridden it? If `[super onEnter]` isn't called when you do, the CCNode doesn't have it's actions started

Comment: I had not done that.. Now I did and it works as I wanted.. But, what's the need to over-ride it?

Comment: Not sure. It sound as if you have overridden it..
I'll post my comment as an answer anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you overridden `onEnter` in your class? Did you remember to call `[super onEnter]`?

Comment: Please don't forget to mark the answer as correct. If you do find out why you needed to call it, you should add to the answer so that other people with the same issue are informed.

Comment: Just had this problem and came across my **own answer**. :D